# Diminished chord constructed over the tonic degree?

Tags: harmony, functional-harmony

I have heard in certain songs the usage of a diminished chord in a major tonality which I think is not constructed over the seventh degree nor over the second degree.

Moreover, in the two examples at which I have found this resource, I have noticed that it is used with the same chord-sequence: *I - i°? - I.*

The two examples I mention are these ones:

- [John Field - Nocturne no 5 in B flat major](https://youtu.be/14QphtxLZ3w) (at the second beat)
- [Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody](https://youtu.be/fJ9rUzIMcZQ?t=190) (Here, with sheet music: [Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody](https://youtu.be/uzr3lKmhado?t=186))

How and why does this technique work? Does it have any particular name?

Comment: Possibly you're under the misapprehension that chords to a pice must be diatonic? Since there are in reality only three diminished chords, and all can and will fit into any key, it's not unusual. Instead of stacking a M3 and a m3, or m3 and M3, it merely stacks two m3s. In these cases from the tonic root.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This technique is called a "common tone diminished chord." As the name implies, this is a diminished chord that shares note ("common tone") with the chord preceding it and the chord after it. Common tone diminished chords are used purely as a chromatic embellishment of the harmony; as opposed to traditional diminished chords that act as a dominant and can be used to modulate to different keys.

Comment: that's it!
http://www2.siba.fi/muste1/index.php?id=90&la=en

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't have any function (dominant, leading, etc.)? How would this be written with roman numerals, this way? I - i° - I?

Comment: @Quaerendo Yes, I - i° - I would be a good way to analyze the progression in your example. In terms of function, I would say it is an example of non-functional harmony; it is meant to elaborate on the tonic, but it doesn't pull the harmony towards the dominant.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the common tone diminished, there is a type of chord consisting of a fully diminished chord viio built over a tonic pedal.  In Spanish we have a label for those, acorde de sobretonica, I did not find the translation in English for this label. The examples in this page are clear
http://cpms-armoniadecuarto.blogspot.com/2009/02/acordes-de-sobretonica.html